# Distribution of maximum of i.i.d. exponential random variables

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Let ($X_i$) be an i.i.d. sequence of exponentially distributed random variables with common parameter 2. Let $M_n = max_{1 \le i \le n}(X_i)$. Then we have $P(M_n \le x)= \prod_{i=1}^n P(X_i \le x)=(1-e^{-2x})^n$, if $x \ge 0$. My question is: Can we find some normalising contants $a_n,b_n >0$ and real-valued random variable $Z$, s.t. $(M_n-b_n)/a_n \to Z$ in distribution? Try to make $Z$ as easy as possible.
Please help, thanks.

Comment: $Z$ will be a [Gumbel distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gumbel_distribution).  There are various choices for $a_n$ and $b_n$ because we only care about asymptotic behaviour.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/105745/extreme-value-theory-show-normal-to-gumbel

Comment: I think the question is about $\frac {(M_n -b_n)} {a_n}$ not $\frac {(X_n -b_n)} {a_n}$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yes it is about $M_n$, but this is commonly written as the order statistic $X_{(n)}$